# Set specific color in ggplot2 using scale_fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am visualizing missing data in R using [this method](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot-your-missing-data-2/) which uses ggplot2:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot_missing <- function(x){
  x %>% 
    is.na %>%
    melt %>%
    ggplot(data = .,
           aes(x = Var2,
               y = Var1)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
    scale_fill_grey(name = "", labels = c("Present","Missing")) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5)) + 
    labs(x = "Columns / Attributes",
         y = "Rows / Observations")
}
```

The scale_fill_grey method uses black and grey. How can I change the color of the cells to a specific color, say "red"?

I have tried:

```
 scale_fill_brewer(name = "", labels = c("Present","Missing"), na.val="red")
```

Also,

```
 scale_fill_gradient(name = "", labels = c("Present","Missing"), low = "#FF69B4", high = "#FF0000")
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Comment: Don't use `scale_fill_grey`? Try `scale_fill_brewer` or `scale_fill_gradient`, or the like.

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned I tried that. I don't see how to set a specific color. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_brewer.html

Comment: Yes, and "a specific color" is different than "something other than black". You should give an example color in your question. And if you tried `scale_fill_gradient` and it didn't work, I'd be curious to see the code that you tried. The documentation  and examples at `?scale_fill_gradient` seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by replacing scale_fill_grey with the following:

```
scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c('my_color_1', 'my_color_2'), labels = c("Present","Missing")) +
```